# Devise's current_user doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I rather clumsily replaced my own auth system (based on Michael Hartl's tutorial) with the Devise gem today.

I've got most things working again but have a lot of errors relating to use of `current_user`.

This, for instance, doesn't work any more:

```
<% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```

I previously had current_user defined in a sessions helper as follows:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end
end
      def current_user=(user)
        @current_user = user
      end

      def current_user
        remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
      end

      def current_user?(user)
        user == current_user
      end
```

I've done away with that, thinking that devise provided the same functionality but that doesn't seem to be the case. In almost all of the situations where I was previously using current_user I now get `undefined method`current_user?'`. I'm hoping there is something global I can do to make the old usages work?

Any pointers much appreciated. I've had by far my worst day of rails in the six months I've been using it.

**EDIT:** The comments explain that I no longer have `current_user?` defined. I've tried adding the following to my users_controller but it doesn't seem to have worked:

```
  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end
```

Comment: You had `current_user` defined, but not `current_user?`, at least in what you show here.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include enough of my old code. Do I just need to define `current_user?` again? If so where, since I'm not using the concept of a session?

Comment: There is no method `current_user?` in Devise, only `current_user`. If you use it anywhere in your code, you need to define it by yourself in users_helper or application_helper. In fact in any helper, all of them works in any view and controller.

Comment: If you're using Devise, you're using a session, unless you explicitly changed its behavior. But if you want a `current_user?` then yes--it probably would have been quicker to just try it.

Comment: Ok. What I want to do in the above example is say "If the current_user is an admin and if they are not the user in question here, then put a delete button". Can I do this with current_user or do I need current_user?

Comment: `if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user)` and `if current_user.admin? && user != current_user` will do the same, according to your helpers. So, it depends on you, which one you want to use. Try to avoid a lot of logic in views, it is a good practice.

Comment: Add it to helper. Not controller. To users_helper or application_helper.

Comment: Brilliant. That `!=` does the trick. I've edited my question above. I'd like to avoid the logic in the views but haven't managed to redefine current_user?

Comment: I see, I needed it in users_helper. It works now. Want to put that in an answer Peter so I can tick it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You deleted your `current_user?(user)` method with `sessions_helper`. Now Devise do all the necessary for you, but Devise has only `current_user` method, no `current_user?(user)`.

You can define it by yourself in any helper, methods from all of them works in any view and any controller.

In fact, if you have many conditions, where you need to check if user is admin, and user isn't a current_user. You can make a separate helper for it. But, as I remember from Michael Hartl's tutorial, there is not many such blocks (:

Something like:

```
def not_admin?(user)
  current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user)
end
```

So, you can refactor you view:

```
<% if not_admin?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```

Also you can make it more clear with:

```
| <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: "You sure?" } if not_admin?(user) %>
```

Comment: Thank you. Really nicely spelt out. I've learnt a lot there. You're a real pro. Really appreciate it.